# Filter no work laravel rtconner/laravel-tagging

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

my filter isn't working it doesn't filter only for posts that contain tag it just displays the most recent posts,
Does anyone have an idea how this could be resolved?

I'm using `rtconner/laravel-tagging`

My query

```
->when($this->filter && $this->filter === 'TAG', function ($query) {
    return $query->with(['tagged' => function($query) {
        $query->select('tag_name')->from('tagging_tagged');
    }]);
```

---

##### DebugBarImage

[image]

Comment: `$query->select('tag_name')` should probably be something like `$query->where('tag_name', $this->filter)`

Comment: @ceejayoz same problem return all post collection :(

Comment: We did answer (or we were trying to help you) yesterday, why did you delete the question and ask again? Don't do that please. Where you able to fix yesterday's database issue or is this the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this in a long time, but I think your issue is that you are using `->from(...)`, that means that you are "overwriting" the query to exactly be `SELELCT xxxx FROM yyyy`, you don't want that, if you specifically want to ONLY get `tag_name`, just use `->select('tag_name');`:

```php
->when($this->filter && $this->filter === 'TAG', function ($query) {
    return $query->with(['tagged' => function($query) {
        $query->select('tag_name');
    }]);
```

I am not sure why you are eager loading with `select` (and `from`), but the idea is that you already have the relationship defined on the model that is calling `->when` (reationship: `tagged`), and you just modify that eager loading (if you want). I am assuming you just want to get `tag_name` and no more properties (columns).

---

If you only want `tag_name`, you can also take advantage of [this section of the documentation about it](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns), so your code would be like this:

```php
->when($this->filter && $this->filter === 'TAG', function ($query) {
    return $query->with('tagged:id,tag_name');
```

Comment: return all colletion same problem :( my full class for querys https://pastebin.com/DtSELH8L

Comment: When you say _all collection_, are you refering that it is giving you all tags that do not belongs to that model? like literally everything instead of the relationship?